# Python not recognised in windows prompt cmd

Tags: python, cmd

Anconda prompt:

```
where conda
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat

where python
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

So i went to environment variables and added path of anaconda and python. Path added:

```
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\shail\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\condabin
```

But when I type on windows cmd:

```
C:\Users\shail>conda --version
conda 4.8.3

 C:\Users\shail>python --version

  C:\Users\shail>
```

So there is **no response from windows cmd on version of python**, so I guess it is **not recognising python**. I mainly need to use pip command, for that I need python first. I dont have python separately installed on system. It is inside my anaconda. On some sites it is written I should not download python separately and add its path because that will confuse the computer since there will be 2 pythons; one from Anaconda and one downloaded separately. So sticking to the anaconda version of python.

**How to get my anaconda version of python recognised ?**

Comment: Did you add python to you Path environment variable? Check out the "important" note at https://realpython.com/installing-python/#step-2-run-the-installer

Comment: the path to python.exe and script folder should be defined in windows environment

Comment: on cmd type path check for python path present if not follows this https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: my python is not added seprately, it is added in anaconda and I couldnt find any scripts path for python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip worked for me after restarting my computer. Though python is still not returning any output but pip is working fine.